# Is it possible, in a for loop, to redo a specific line with new condition? And in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I have a for loop that is looking in some data and if there is a cell that contain nothing, it put "N/A". Some times some data are not on the same line. So is there a way, in a for loop, to look for the empty cell and if there's a empty cell look if the label is the same on some other line? here the labels are the same (310) but they are on two different lines.
I thought about merging those two lines but i'm don't know exactly what to look for! is there a simple fonction that can help me or will i have to make somthing up?

headers:

label|bit|x1 |y1 || label|bit |x2 |y2||x1-x2 |y1-y2

[image]

this is the for loop i have the `missing label` and the `orphan label` means that it's missing a label on the line

```
For labelsdiligne2 = 2 To DernLigne
    a = Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 4 * ver - 3)
    b = Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 4 * (ver + 1) - 3)
    c = Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 4 * ver - 2)
    d = Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 4 * (ver + 1) - 2)
    If a = "" Or b = "" Then
        Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 9).Value = "N/A"
        Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 10).Value = "N/A"
        If a = "" Then
            Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 15).Value = "Orphan Label"
        ElseIf b = "" Then
            Sheets(5).Cells(labelsdiligne2, 15).Value = "Missing Label"
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Can you share some headers and a little more data? One example is not enough to understand the structure of your data. The issue sounds to be structural so understanding that will likely help

Comment: Please add your actual code - that will clarify exactly what you're currently doing, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I'm certain there's a way, but without seeing your code we can't help too much.

Comment: there! i updated a new picture, part of my code and some more info.